# "using namespace std;" before any #include?

Tags: c++, namespaces, using-directives

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ordering of using namespace std; and includes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841130/ordering-of-using-namespace-std-and-includes)

I can remember that I read a tutorial that started all its source files with

```
using namespace std;
```

When I tested that with my GCC compiler it accepted the code. But is such code valid?

Comment: What makes you think it wont work?

Comment: @roh i have this bad feeling inside..

Comment: is this one of your trick questions?

Comment: "It isnt right but still it works kind of feeling"

Comment: @jalf what? it makes me scratch my head why it knows of std even without any headers included?!

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb FWIW, Microsofts C++ compiler 16.x / VS2010, allows it as well. It does not allow, however, `using namespace I_MADE_THIS_UP;` without any header that actually defines it.

Comment: ohh this question has already been asked. please vote for close and delete, folks.

Comment: clang++ gives a warning btw :  warning: using directive refers to implicitly-defined namespace 'std'. I don't know what makes 'std' implicitly defined namespace.

Comment: @pra doug and me discussed that in the clang irc channel back then. since operator new is implicitly declared, some compilers apparently make that declaration make namespace "std" visible. but the spec is clear that the implicit declaration of operator new shall not make any other names visible.

Comment: similar for the various builtin exception types...

Answer (score 2):

It's valid, provided you define the namespace `std` before:

```
namespace std {}
using namespace std;
```

It's probably not a very good idea, however, as it imposes a `using
namespace std;` on all of the included headers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's perfectly valid.

Actually, after reading the title again . . . If you include it before any included headers, not so much. It's "valid", but not good practice.

See [C++: What's happen when I use "using namespace xyz" before #include<headerxy>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6895020/c-whats-happen-when-i-use-using-namespace-xyz-before-includeheaderxy)

Comment: What shall i do with the linked page? it doesnt provide evidence for your claim or i couldnt find it. can you please help me once again finding it?

Comment: Yeah sorry, just updated my post.

Comment: This answer is just wrong, this has nothing to do with good practice but with conformity to the standard. And according to the quotes provided in response to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6841130/20984), the code is not valid (even though the standard seems a bit ambiguous).

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the only differences of using **using namespace std;** and not using it, is that when you use it you might run into conflicts in your code variables later (clashing of names).
In addition it might contaminated someone else's namespace since when you use it you include everything in the **namespace std** so it's advisable not to you use it in header files. but it's up to you to use it in cpp files or not.

**std::cin** or **cin**, only difference is laziness imo. But using **using namespace std;** *is* valid.

**EDIT:** (For references and more clarification)

found those two references on the subject, i think you'll find the second one more helpful on why it's *valid* and works fine, but it's considered *bad practice* in some cases. 
Please check [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/25538/) and [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-a-bad-practice-in-c)

Quotes:

> I recommend you avoid using directives; using declarations make a lot
>   more sense, although, personally, I would just rather use the fully
>   qualified name.

for example, you can use:

```
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
```

instead of using the whole std.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the compilers follows the standard especially the fundamental specifications like this will be perfectly made par to the standard. But being an programmer I never used the declaration unless required. Most of the cases I have seen are with the school kind of programs. In the real production we've to make sense with the usage and these kind of declarations will be made close the place where we start using it. But never used before includes though it works!